# Ho to get rid of $$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ while writing springboot log

Tags: spring-boot

I am writing springboot log which is appending like below, I just wanted to see only my class name. i.e just "h.c.d.DmsComponentsTestApplication - test text"

```
2020-06-12 13:31:40 INFO  h.c.d.DmsComponentsTestApplication**$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43508b02** - test text
```

**application.yaml:**

pattern:
        console: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n'

Comment: How do you create a logger?

Comment: private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

Comment: Then create it as `LoggerFactory.getLogger(DmsComponentsTestApplication.class)`.

Comment: Perfect, this looks OK now...thanks  @krzysztof-kaszkowiak